# How to get max(date) from a group of joined tables in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server, maxdate

I have four tables that I am joining to get some data I need. The tables and some sample data are as follows:

```
**TollTransaction table**       
AccountId   EntryTransDt    LicPlateNo
1655024     24-05-2017          ABC123
1655024     24-05-2017          DEF123
1655024     24-05-2017          GHI123
1655024     24-05-2017          JKL123
1655024     24-05-2017          MNO123


**Plate table**     
AccountId   LicPlateNo  EndDate
11001       ABC123      2012-06-10
1898884     ABC123      NULL
1981834     DEF123      NULL
14066       GHI123      NULL
1770746     JKL123      NULL
1005010     MNO123      NULL


**Account table**       
AccountId   AccountNumber   CurrentBalance
11001       10110014        0
14066       10140668        0
1005010     20050108        0
1770746     27707463        3.9
1898884     28988847        0
1981834     29818345        0


**FinTransMaster table**        
FinTransTypeCode    BusinessDay AcctID
PYMT                03-02-2015  11001
PYMT                15-01-2015  11001
PYMT                11-12-2014  14066
PYMT                11-09-2014  14066
PYMT                01-04-2016  1005010
PYMT                02-10-2014  1005010
PYMT                15-09-2015  1770746
PYMT                30-11-2015  1898884
PYMT                21-10-2015  1898884
PYMT                23-03-2017  1981834
```

The AccountId in TollTransaction table is the same for those Licence plates because those licence plates follow a common criteria.

I need to get AccountIds from the Plate table and then join the Account table on AccountIds to get the AccountNumber.

**What I'm trying to do:**
1) I'm trying to find Accounts that have a Current Balance in payment.
2) The last date the payment was made (max BusinessDay from FinTransMaster table).
3) The last EntryTransDt in TollTransaction table for that LicPlateNo.

**My code is as follows:**

```
SELECT A.AccountNumber
      ,A.CurrentBalance
      ,(SELECT MAX(BusinessDay) FROM FinTransMaster F WHERE A.AccountId = F.AcctID AND FinTransTypeCode = 'PYMT' GROUP BY AcctID) Last_Pymt_Date
      ,(SELECT MAX(EntryTransDt) FROM TollTransaction GROUP BY LicPlateNo) Last_Transaction

FROM TollTransaction T
INNER JOIN Plate P ON T.LicPlateNo = P.LicPlateNo
INNER JOIN Account A ON P.AccountId = A.AccountId
--INNER JOIN FinTransMaster F ON A.AccountId = F.AcctID

WHERE T.AccountId = '1655024'
  AND P.EndDate IS NULL
  AND A.CurrentBalance > 0

ORDER BY Last_Pymt_Date DESC, A.AccountNumber
```

My code is wrong in the two SELECT MAX() queries.

What code I would need to use there to get the last dates?

**EDIT:**
I used the code suggested in the answer below but got way too many records. The code I used was:

```
SELECT A.AccountNumber
      ,A.CurrentBalance
      --,(SELECT MAX(BusinessDay) FROM FinTransMaster F WHERE A.AccountId = F.AcctID AND FinTransTypeCode = 'PYMT' GROUP BY AcctID) Last_Pymt_Date
      --,(SELECT MAX(EntryTransDt) FROM TollTransaction GROUP BY LicPlateNo) Last_Transaction
      ,MAX(F.BusinessDay) over(Partition by F.AcctID) as Last_Pymt_date
      ,MAX(T.EntryTransDt) over(Partition by T.LicPlateNo) as Last_Transaction
FROM TollTransaction T
INNER JOIN Plate P ON T.LicPlateNo = P.LicPlateNo
INNER JOIN Account A ON P.AccountId = A.AccountId
LEFT JOIN FinTransMaster F ON A.AccountId = F.AcctID

WHERE T.AccountId = '1655024'
  AND P.EndDate IS NULL
  AND A.CurrentBalance > 0

ORDER BY Last_Pymt_Date DESC, A.AccountNumber
```

But I got way too many records.

My TollTransactions table has multiple records for the same LicPlateNo. That is why I'm getting multiple records after the JOINs. If I could JOIN only Distinct T.LicPlateNo to the other tables, I should get single records.

Comment: Join your subqueries to your id. `WHERE T.AccountID = F.AccountId` and `WHERE T.AccountId = TollTransaction.AccountId`

Comment: T.AccountID is NOT equal to F.AccountID. Hence, I have to join the Plate table where Plate.AccountID = F.AccountID

Answer (score 0):

you can try using join as below:

```
SELECT A.AccountNumber
      ,A.CurrentBalance
      --,(SELECT MAX(BusinessDay) FROM FinTransMaster F WHERE A.AccountId = F.AcctID AND FinTransTypeCode = 'PYMT' GROUP BY AcctID) Last_Pymt_Date
      --,(SELECT MAX(EntryTransDt) FROM TollTransaction GROUP BY LicPlateNo) Last_Transaction
      ,MAX(F.BusinessDay) over(Partition by F.AcctID) as Last_Pymt_date
      ,MAX(T.EntryTransDt) over(Partition by T.LicPlateNo) as Last_Transaction
FROM TollTransaction T
INNER JOIN Plate P ON T.LicPlateNo = P.LicPlateNo
INNER JOIN Account A ON P.AccountId = A.AccountId
LEFT JOIN FinTransMaster F ON A.AccountId = F.AcctID

WHERE T.AccountId = '1655024'
  AND P.EndDate IS NULL
  AND A.CurrentBalance > 0

ORDER BY Last_Pymt_Date DESC, A.AccountNumber
```

Comment: Thank you, Kannan. EntryTransDt is only in TollTransaction table T. So, I'm trying ,MAX(T.EntryTransDt) over...     Running the code now. Waiting for results. Will let you know how it goes. Thanks again.

Comment: After 31 minutes of running, I got an error message that said 'Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.SORT temporary run storage:  140840636776448' in database 'tempdb' because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full.'  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide execution plan?

Comment: What if I just get F.BusinessDay and T.EntryTransDt and ORDER them descending order and then put it all in a temp table . Then select Top1 of each? Would that work? What would the code be for that?

Comment: Not required what is record counts for tolltransaction, other tables and appropriate indexes will help

Comment: I think it is a problem of joins. I ran a simple query to SELECT A.ACcountNumber, A.CurrentBalance FROM TollTransaction T  INNER JOIN Plate P ON T.LicPlateNo = P.LicPlateNo  INNER JOIN Account A ON P.AccountId = A.AccountId  WHERE T.AccountId = '1655024' AND P.EndDate IS NULL AND A.CurrentBalance > 0  ___  But in the results, I get multiple records for the same AccountNumber. Total 6.3 million records.

Comment: My TollTransactions table has multiple records for the same LicPlateNo. That is why I'm getting multiple records after the JOINs. If I could JOIN only Distinct T.LicPlateNo to the other tables, I should get single records.